# Baire's theorem in calculus

Tags: calculus, general-topology, functional-analysis

We have a Baire's theorem in calculus that says if we have a closed not empty subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $F = \bigcup_{n}F_{i}$ (countable union of closed sets), then $\exists N,(a,b): F\cap(a,b) \neq \varnothing$ and $F\cap(a,b) \subset F_{N}$. But why it works with rational numbers. For example, let's say that $F_{i} = x_i$, where $x_{i}$ is a rational number. Then, $F = \bigcup_{n}F_{i}$ is a set of rational numbers. But in any range (a,b) we have an infinite number of rational numbers. Then, $F\cap(a,b) \not\subset F_{N}$ $\forall N, (a,b)$ because of $F_{N}$ is a single number but $F\cap(a,b)$ contains infinite number of rational numbers. What is wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @NoahSchweber It is like a mini Baire's theorem in calculus not in functional analysis

Comment: I'm assuming that you mean that $(x_i)_{i\in \mathbb N}$ is an enumeration of the rationals, not just some rationals. In that case, the set of rational numbers is not closed in $\mathbb R$

Comment: Why it is not closed? Any point is a closed set in $\mathbb{R}$, doesn't matter it is rational or natural or irrational. For example, $(1)$ is a  closed set in $\mathbb{R}$. It affect only if we take union of that points. And because of countable union of closed sets like rational numbers is a closed set, then F is a closed set.

Comment: @nameisnoname The countable union of closed sets is **not** always closed. (And indeed this is a counterexample.) Why do you think it is?